# Cannot transform labels on spinning globe

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement a version of Mike Bostock's spinny globe and to overlay country labels. This has been achieved successfully here: http://bl.ocks.org/dwtkns/4686432

Unfortunately I am not able to implement this with my own code for reasons that elude me. And I wonder whether this could also not be due to the fact I have added a zoom function.

This is how I initialize the labels

```
    var label = svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(collection.features)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
//      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + //path.centroid(d) + ")"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name;} );
```

This is how I try to transform the labels

```
function position_labels() {
  var centerPos = projection.invert([width/2,height/2]);

  var arc = d3.geo.greatArc();

  svg.selectAll(".label")
    .attr("text-anchor",function(d) {
      var x = projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[0];
      return x < width/2-20 ? "end" :
             x < width/2+20 ? "middle" :
             "start"
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      var loc = projection(d.geometry.coordinates),
        x = loc[0],
        y = loc[1];
      var offset = x < width/2 ? -5 : 5;
      return "translate(" + (x+offset) + "," + (y-2) + ")"
    })
    .style("display",function(d) {
      var d = arc.distance({source: d.geometry.coordinates, target: centerPos});
      return (d > 1.57) ? 'none' : 'inline';
    })

}
```

My code can be found here. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/3078L7x2/

Your help would be very much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to keep updating the position of the labels everytime the globe moves. I modified your code a bit, adding comment `// update` for my changes. This only moves the labels along with the globe. But hopefully helpful as starting point. http://jsfiddle.net/3078L7x2/4/

```
function position_labels() {
    // var centerPos = projection.invert([width/2,height/2]);
    // var arc = d3.geo.greatArc();
    // update: update path projection before applying it to labels position
    path.projection(projection);
    svg.selectAll(".label").attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
        // svg.selectAll(".label")
        //   .attr("text-anchor",function(d) {
        //     var x = projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[0];
        //     return x < width/2-20 ? "end" :
        //            x < width/2+20 ? "middle" :
        //            "start"
        //   })
        // .attr("transform", function(d) {
        //   var loc = projection(d.geometry.coordinates),
        //     x = loc[0],
        //     y = loc[1];
        //   var offset = x < width/2 ? -5 : 5;
        //   return "translate(" + (x+offset) + "," + (y-2) + ")"
        // })
        //   .style("display",function(d) {
        //     var d = arc.distance({source: d.geometry.coordinates, target: centerPos});
        //     return (d > 1.57) ? 'none' : 'inline';
        //   })
}
```

calling `position_labels()` after appending `text` and in `startAnimation()` and `move()`.

Comment: Phoa -that is incredible that I forgot to refresh the animation. Very dumb indeed. I have made progress on your code and have amended the code so that it hides label on the other side of the earth. I (think I) do this by calculating the distance between path centroids and the center position of the globe. But for some reason it seems to be inconsistent and hiding the wrong labels... I have saved my work in the following jsfiddle -please let me know what I am doing wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/kh3kegsy/

Comment: @Noobster - I modified the `position_labels` function, using the `circle.clip(d)` to hide the label.. the same way the path of the country is drawn on the map. here's the fiddle - [http://jsfiddle.net/kh3kegsy/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/kh3kegsy/5/)